# Change Dropdowns selected item on button click

Tags: jquery, web-services, webforms

I have a drop down list with data loaded now I want to change selected item of drop down on button click which provides Id from webservice.

Below is my webmethod:

```
 [WebMethod]
        public string EditData(int sid) //Show the edit clicked data in the popup window
        {
            string jsondata;
            //var details = new List<Employee>();
           DataTable dt =  bllsubcat.GetSubCategoryById(sid);
            jsondata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);


            return jsondata;
        }
```

And this is my ajax call:

```
  $(document).on("click", ".editButton", function () {
                        $('#myModal').focus();
                        var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                        console.log(id);
                        $("#btnUpdate").attr("edit-id", id);
                        //alert(id);  //getting the row id 
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "Post",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            url: "SubCategoryService.asmx/EditData",
                            data: '{sid: ' + id + '}',
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                var subcatdet = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                                $.each(subcatdet, function (index, value) {
                                    $("#ddlCategory1").val(value.CategoryName);
                                    $("#txtSubCatName1").val(value.SubCategoryName);
                                });

                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("Error while retrieving data of :" + id);
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

From above code

```
$("#txtSubCatName1").val(value.SubCategoryName);
$("#ddlCategory1").val(value.CategoryName);
```

loads value to textbox successfully but selected item of drop down is not changed.

Below is my code to load drop down:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "SubCategoryService.asmx/LoadCategory",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var ddlCategory = $("[id*=ddlCategory1]");
                    ddlCategory.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                    $.each(r.d, function () {
                        ddlCategory.append($("<option></option>").val(this['CategoryId']).html(this['CategoryName']));
                    });

                },
                error: function (Result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set options value your way, your options should have value, like this:

```
<select id="ddlCategory1">
      <option value="1">Food</option>
      <option value="2" selected="1">Clothes</option>
      <option value="3">Drinks</option>
</select>
```

In asp.net c# code behind it can be look like this:

```
ddlCategory1.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
ddlCategory1.DataValueField = "CategoryID";
```

Then you select them by category id (not name) like this:

```
$("#ddlCategory1").val(value.CategoryID);
```

Another option is to select by option's text like this:

```
$('#ddlCategory1 option').filter(function() { 
    return ($(this).text() == value.CategoryName); 
}).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: My options value is not like above but options are loaded from database.My drop down is filled with data base now I want tio change value on button click.

Comment: Hi @Sumit Bhattarai. So, your template should also set attribute value of options. for example: <option value="<%cat.id%>"><%cat.name%></option>. Another option to select by name I already mentioned in the answer, maybe you can share your code of options generation?

Comment: @Sumit Bhattarai, I've edited my answer to include a c# code example, but it depends what is your way to fill the list. Also fixed the code of selecting by name at the bottom